# Is this a good way to get event content and index from list items?

Tags: javascript

I have this, that works, but wonder if it can be done better/simpler/easier/better? The code needs to return both the content and the index of the list item selected. (pure javascript only please)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name=“viewport” content=“width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0”>

<head>
    <title>TestClick</title>
</head>

<body>
    <ul id = "animals">
        <li>Dog</li>
        <li>Cat</li>
        <li>Pig</li>
        <li>Cow</li>
        <li>Hen</li>
    </ul>
    <div id = "output"></div>
    <script>
    var mylist = document.getElementById("animals");
    var thelis = mylist.getElementsByTagName('li');
    var arrlis = Array.from(thelis);
    
    for (var i=0; i<thelis.length; i++) {
        thelis[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
            var content = this.innerHTML;
            var index = arrlis.indexOf(this) + 1;
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = ( content + " " + index);     
        });
    }   
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Suggestion to add click listener to just the ul tag and by event delegation you can get to know where the click came from .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you’re using `Array.from` without a polyfill, you can probably rely on many other ES6 improvements like `let` declarations, which allow you to refer to `i` in the callback for the index and get the correct (iteration-specific) value. (This also makes `arrlis` unused.)
- If the list contained nested lists, would you also want to include those elements in `thelis`? If the answer is that you wouldn’t want that or that the situation isn’t applicable, use the `children` property of the list to get the list elements.

```js
let mylist = document.getElementById("animals");

for (let i = 0; i < mylist.children.length; i++) {
    mylist.children[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        let content = this.innerHTML;
        let index = i + 1;
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = content + " " + index;     
    });
}
```

Comment: This seems the most concise and understandable so far. It was the use of "children" I was missing. (children has been around for ages but somehow passed me by....)

Answer (score 1):

As Harmandeep suggested, it's good to use event delegation and grab the target from there to minimize extra event listeners.

```js
const ul = document.getElementById('animals')
const output = document.getElementById('output');

const children = Array.from(ul.children)

ul.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const text = e.target.textContent;
    const index = children.findIndex(child => child == e.target);

    output.innerHTML = `${text} ${index}`
})
```

```html
<ul id="animals">
  <li>Dog</li>
  <li>Cat</li>
  <li>Pig</li>
  <li>Cow</li>
  <li>Hen</li>
</ul>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Note the `findIndex` can be simplified to `indexOf`: `children.indexOf(e.target)`

Comment: @ Phix & @ Harmandeep This sounds very plausible, given my eventual use will be on a list in the hundreds of "li"s, reducing the number of eventListeners sounds good!

Answer (score 1):

Solution using one click event listener on ul rather than using on all list elements. This is called as **event delegation**, by default it is **event bubbling**.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name=“viewport” content=“width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0”>

<head>
    <title>TestClick</title>
</head>

<body>
    <ul id = "animals">
        <li>Dog</li>
        <li>Cat</li>
        <li>Pig</li>
        <li>Cow</li>
        <li>Hen</li>
    </ul>
    <div id = "output"></div>
    <script>
    
    var mylist = document.getElementById("animals");
    var target;
    
    mylist.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      target = event.target;
      let li = target.closest('li'); // get reference by using closest
      let nodes = Array.from( li.closest('ul').children ); // get array
      let index = nodes.indexOf( li ); 
 
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "CONTENT: "+target.innerHTML + " ---- INDEX: " +index;
      
      
   })
    
    
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```